# Is there a way to find the published URL of all owned Google Sites?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-sites, gam

I've been using GAM to locate all google site Drive files in my workspace domain and now have a list of addresses like this:

> https://sites.google.com/d/1450940359u5609586456/edit

I'm trying to find a way to locate the published URL of the drive google site file but I'm not sure it's possible. GAM does not provide the info when the drive file is interogated. I'm interested in any solution, not just based on GAM.

Comment: If I understood correctly you would like to list the URLs of all the files in your Google Drive. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @OriolCastander I am trying to find the addresses of all sites published by members of my workspace domain. At the moment all I can obtain is the source files in the user's Drives.
drive locations look like this: https://sites.google.com/d/1450940359u5609586456/edit

whereas published urls look like this: https://sites.google.com/myorg.com/sitename/home

Comment: That is not possible, at least it is not directly possible from Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to get a site's published URL using GAM. GAM relies on Google's APIs and there is not one available for new Sites:

> The Sites APIs currently support only classic Sites. These APIs do not support new Sites.
> --  https://support.google.com/a/answer/7181011?hl=en

Despite Google's repeated assurances that new Sites would be able to do everything classic Sites did, seven years on this is one of a number of unfilled gaps.

If you are only interested in sites with a "Custom URL," these can easily be viewed in the Google Workspace Admin under Apps → Google Workspace → Sites → Custom URL:

[image: Screenshot showing where to find Custom URL mapping]

If you want to know about all sites, there is no good solution I'm aware of. One possible workaround is to give yourself access to every single site using GAM and then inspect each Site manually or using some sort of RPA or browser scripting tool.

Before you start down this path, generate a list of all the Sites in your domain and export it to Google Sheets (the quantity of results might help you decide how far to pursue this idea):

```
gam all users show filelist todrive query "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.site'"
```

**Hint:** To narrow down the scope of this and all other GAM commands listed here you may want to replace `all users` with `ou "OU/Sub-OU"` or you could audit a subset of users by adding them to a new group called sites-audit-users@example.com and use `group sites-audit-users` throughout.

If you decide to proceed, the high level steps are:

1. Create an "Auditor" group to use for this process
2. Give the Auditor group edit access to all the sites in the domain
3. Inspect all the sites (manually or automatically)
4. Delete the Auditor group

#### 1. Create Auditor group and add yourself

```
gam create group name "Sites Auditor - April 2023" email sites.auditor@example.org
gam update group sites.auditor@example.org add owner user my.name@example.org
```

#### 2. Give the Auditor group access to all sites

```
gam all users show filelist id title alternateLink query "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.site'" | tee sites.csv | gam csv - gam user ~Owner add drivefileacl ~id group sites.auditor@example.org role editor
```

**Note:** This uses `tee` to both pipe the output to the next GAM command **and** save it to a file called `sites.csv` in your current directory. Windows users may need to install a version of `tee` themselves for this command to work.

#### 3. Inspect all the sites

The sites will all be listed in `sites.csv`. You can open the edit interface for each site (manually or programmatically) using the URL in the `alternateLink` column.

If inspecting manually, open the "Publish settings..." screen under the "Publish" dropdown menu:

[image: Screenshot showing the "Publish settings..." menu option]

If inspecting using some sort of browser scripting or RPA tool such as [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev), [UIPath](https://www.uipath.com) or [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/), be aware that some sites may have one or more custom URLs in addition to their "normal" URL:

[image: Screenshot of a site with additional custom URLs]

#### 4. Delete the Auditor group

> **Optional but thorough:** Deleting the group will effectively remove the permissions from all the sites but an ACL entry for the deleted group will remain in each file. If you wish to be more thorough you should first remove the Auditor group permission from each file using the CSV we saved earlier:
>
> ```
> gam csv sites.csv gam user ~Owner delete drivefileacl ~id group sites.auditor@example.org
> ```

```
gam delete group sites.auditor@example.org
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible to find the Site's published URL from the source Drive file.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to find all google Drive files in your workspace using GAM.

However,it can be easily achieved using google **Apps Script** and the [**DriveApp**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) class. By using the `getFiles()` function (you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles)) you can retrieve a list of all your files in **Google Drive**. Then you can extract the url of those files quite easily, like in the example below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var iterator = DriveApp.getFiles();

  while (iterator.hasNext()){
    var file = iterator.next();
    console.log(file.getUrl());
  }
}
```

Comment: getUrl() will provide the URL of the drive file, not the publishsed URL of the site. As you commented previously, there doesn't appear to be a way to achieve what I'm trying to do.